# numpy.random.uniform applied to index of array produces integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I want to populate an array with uniformly chosen floats, but when I try to do that I get integers instead:

```
#Initial parameters
P = np.full(1, 0)
lower_bounds = np.full(1, 0)
upper_bounds = np.full(1, np.pi)

def candidate(P):
    for k in range(len(P)):
        P[k] = np.random.uniform(lower_bounds[k],upper_bounds[k])
    return P

print(candidate(P))
```

This prints [0], [1], [2], or [3], whereas

```
print(np.random.uniform(lower_bounds[0],upper_bounds[0]))
```

prints a float, as desired. I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Look at `P.dtype`. Then try something like `P[0] = np.pi` and check the value of `P[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialized `P` is became an array of ints.

```py
P = np.full(1, 0)
print(P.dtype)  # prints dtype('int64')
```

When later you assign the result of `np.random.uniform` to `P[k]` the float value returned by `np.random.uniform` was truncated and you just got the integer part.

Use `P = np.full(1,0.0)` or `P = np.full(1,0, dtype=float)` instead.